# Telegram Bot respond to specific command in Python list

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I am making a Telegram bot that can can access database to reply users' query. The bot need to respond to specific request of certain data in database. I was able to solve for when users request for all data but I am stuck with individual data. I am using `telegram.ext` from `telegram` package in python. Here is what I have done so far.

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters
import MySQLdb

currr = [] # global list var ~don't bash me for using global in python please, I'm a newbie

# request for all data in database
def request2(bot, update):
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host = "local", user = "root", passwd = "pwd", db = "mydb")
    cur = db.cursor()
    cur.execute("select ID from table")
    ID = cur.fetchall()

    cur.execute("SELECT ID, temp FROM table2 order by indexs desc")
    each_rows = cur.fetchall()
    for IDs in ID:
        for each_row in each_rows:
            if str(each_row[0])[0:4]==str(ID)[2:6]:
                update.message.reply_text('reply all related data here')
                break

# request for single data
def individualreq(bot, update):
    db = pymysql.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd = "pwd", db = "mydb")
    update.message.reply_text('reply individual data to users here')

def main():
    updater = Updater("TOKEN")
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    global currr
    # get all ID form database
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd = "pwd", db = "mydb")
    cur = db.cursor()
    cur.execute("select ID from table")
    curr_ID = cur.fetchall()

    # example ID = 'F01', 'F02', 'F03'
    for curr_IDs in curr_ID:
        currr.append(curr_IDs[0])

    # request all data
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("all", request2))

    # request individual data
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler(currr, individualreq)) # list command in currr[]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am looking for a way to pass the current command which is also the ID in database that user request in the `currr[]` list to the `individualreq(bot, update)` function so that only data of the called ID is being replied. Users will select from a list of ID in telegram and the command handler can pass the selected ID to the function. I have not found a way to pass the ID to the function. Could someone help me to solve this please. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find out a solution for my question from the answer provided by Oluwafemi Sule. `CommandHandler` can pass the arguments of the command to the function by adding `pass_args=True` in the `CommandHandler`.

```
dp.add_handler(CommandHandler(currr, individualreq, pass_args=True))
```

To print out the args in the function, the function need to receive the args.

```
def individualreq(bot, update, args):
    # id store the args value
    id = update.message.text
    print(id[1:]) # [1:] is to get rid of the / in id
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>You can outright make `individualreq` a closure.</s>

`CommandHandler` takes a command or list of command to listen to and a list other options.
[There is a `pass_user_data` option](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.commandhandler.html#CommandHandler.pass_user_data) that allows for user data to be passed to the callback.

```
dp.add_handler(CommandHandler(currr, individualreq, pass_user_data=True))
```

The signature for `individualreq` callback will be updated to take the `user_data`

```
def individualreq(bot, update, user_data=None):
     #user_data is a dict
     print(user_data)
```

Comment: I tried this but the output is only a blank parentheses [ ]. I also tried the `pass_args=True` but the output is the same.

Comment: Are you polling the dispatcher and testing with a user account?

Comment: Yes I am polling and testing with user account. The bot also can reply to Telegram group.

Comment: Hello. I tried some stuff by looking at the GitHub example on how to use `CommandHandler` [test_commandhandler.py](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/tests/test_commandhandler.py) and find out a way to pass the args to the function. I used `id = update.message.text` to store the passed command into id variable. Thank you very much for your answer sir that guide me to solve this problem